# How to configure properties to show up in the resource details view in the factory monitor?

Tags: moryx

I want to display resource properties in the resource details view in the factory monitor.

So I created a resource with several properties

```
[ResourceRegistration]
public class AssemblyCell: Cell
{
   ...
   
   [EntrySerialize, DataMember]
   public int Value {get;set;}

   [EntrySerialize, DataMember]
   public int TestParameter {get;set;}
}
```

Then I created a `MachineLocation` in the UI and added my AssemblyCell as a child. The cell appears in the factory monitor. But when I click on it in the factory monitor, it says `No property configured`.

[Resource details view in the factory monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5kAB.png)

How can I configure properties? I haven't found anything in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an attribute called `[EntryVisualizationAttribute]` (https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Factory/blob/b27470d5d1b08bc8c97b645044221948ca28d299/src/Moryx.Factory/EntryVisualizationAttribute.cs), which you can add to your properties. Then they will appear in the details view.